# Can sniffling lead to otitis media?

Tags: common-cold, ears-nose-throat-ent, nose-blowing, runny-nose

Is there any link between excessive sniffling when having a runny nose and otitis media? By sniffling I mean propelling thin watery mucus up one's nose into the nasal cavity rather than pulling thick mucus down one's throat.

Where I was brought up, sniffling is strongly frowned upon (almost culturally institutionalized misophonia). Grandparents used to say sniffling can cause otitis media, but I am not able to find any evidence neither for nor against.

Comment: Related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20749/what-are-the-main-problems-with-non-injectable-ways-to-administer-molecules-into

Comment: Search for: _sniffing "otitis media"_ and you'll quickly get to at least one study with clear results.